# Загрузка и скачивание файла из базы Posgresql

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, bytearray

У меня есть база PostgreSQL с таблицей для хранения файлов. Сам файл храниться в поле bytea.
Как мне правильно организовать загрузку и скачивание файла? У меня получается загружать файл в базу, но я не могу его оттуда корректно скачать, т.е. файл скачивается, но видимо в битой кодировке/формате, потому что он не открывается в программе (excel файл). Вот мои обработчики (использую фреймворк Laravel):

Загрузка:

```
public function submit(Request $req){
   if($req->hasFile('upload_file')){
     $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()+60*60*2);
     $file=file_get_contents($req->file('upload_file'));
     $size=$req->file('upload_file')->getSize()/1024;
     $file = base64_encode($file);
     $name=$req->file('upload_file')->getClientOriginalName();
     $user = DB::table('Users')->where('Login', session('user'))->first();
     DB::table('FileJournal')->insert(['name'=>$name,'ID_User'=>$user->ID,'file'=>$file,'Directory'=>"null",'DateInsert'=>$date,'Size'=>$size,'IsLoaded'=>'true']);
     return back()->with('Success',"Файл успешно загружен");
   }
   else {
     return back()->withErrors('Нет файла');
   }
 }
```

Скачиваение:

```
public function download($file_id){
  $dbconn = pg_connect("dbname=resource39 host=62.109.23.82 port=5432 user=resource_admin password=gcdxwYbv717");
  $res = pg_query("SELECT * FROM \"System\".\"FileJournal\" WHERE \"ID\" =".$file_id);
  $row = pg_fetch_assoc($res);
  $size = $row['Size']*1024;
  $file = pg_escape_bytea($row['file']);
  header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
  header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$row['name']);
  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
  header('Expires: 0');
  header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
  header('Pragma: public');
  header('Content-Length: ' . $row['Size']);
  echo $file;
  exit();
   }
```

HTML-Страница

```
@if($errors->any())
  <div class="alert alert-danger">
    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
      {{$error}}
      <br>
    @endforeach
   </div>
@endif
@if(session()->get('Success'))
  <div class="alert alert-success">
    {{session()->get('Success')}}
  </div>
@endif
  <form action="{{route('upload')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <div class="upload_input">
      @csrf
      <input type="file" accept="application/vnd.ms-excel,application/xml,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" name="upload_file" id="upload_file">
      <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
    </div>
  </form>
  <div class="subpage_table">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Наименование файла</td>
          <td>Дата загрузки</td>
          <td>Размер файла</td>
          <td>Пользователь</td>
          <td>Скачать</td>
        </tr>
        <thead>
        <tbody>
          @foreach ($journal as $record)
          <tr>
            <td>{{$record->name}}</td>
            <td>{{date('d.m.Y H:i:s',strtotime($record->DateInsert))}}</td>
            <td>{{round(($record->Size),2)}} Кб</td>
            <td>{{$record->user}}</td>
            <td><a href="{{route('download',['file_id' => $record->ID])}}" download><button><div class="download"></div></button></a></td>
          </tr>
          @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: А вы можете пояснить смысл манипуляций над содержимым файла? Особенно в части использования base64_encode и pg_escape_bytea. Ну и в целом идею писать бинарник файла в базу.

Comment: @Мелкий base64_encode нужен для преобразования файла и возможности его хранения в bytea поле, пример нашел на просторах интернета, pg_escape_bytea честно до конца сам не разобрался для чего, тоже пример находил на просторах интернета. Заказчик хочет хранить файлы в базе и скачивать их оттуда при первой необходимости.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для корректной записи файла в `bytea` `PDO` предлагает об этом прямо заявить посредством указания `PDO::PARAM_LOB`

```
$file = file_get_contents('/usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/postgres');
$p = $pdo->prepare('insert into files (bytea_field) values (?)');
$p->bindParam(1, $file, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
$p->execute();
```

При этом в качестве `$file` можно передавать как собственно строку с бинарным содержимым файла, так и напрямую файловый дескриптор.

Остальную транспортировку драйвер берёт на себя.

---

При чтении поля `bytea` `PDO` вместо строки [предоставит](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.2/ext/pdo_pgsql/pgsql_statement.c#L520) ресурс [`stream`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.stream.php). Потому, содержимое файла необходимо получать именно как `stream`. Например,

```
$row = $pdo->query('select bytea_field from files')->fetch();
$fileContent = stream_get_contents($row['bytea_field']);
```

---

То есть именно то, почему я в комментарии спросил, понимаете ли вы вообще смысл написанных строк в вашем коде. Не стоит бездумно писать какие-то функции. Почему вы хотите писать именно содержимое самих файлов в базу - загадкой осталось.

Comment: загружает, качает, но качает всё равно битый файл, допустим Excel`евский файл скачанный уже не откроется

Comment: берите hex редактор и сравнивайте по содержимому. Что не так в _вашем_ коде. Может у вас BOM-метка или варнинг какой выводится в начале файла.

Comment: он вообще данные теряет по дороге, там просто после 1ой строки пустота идёт

Comment: @Малкой пардон, там мой косяк. Ваш совет помог, большое спасибо!